# Compile Warning Not Encountered When Compiling on Local Machine with ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a slight problem that I'm not sure how to solve.

In our multiple projects we would like to change "Treat Warnings as Errors" (`GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS`) to `YES`.

We would also like to leave the Xcode default project setting of "Build Active Architecture Only" (`ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH`) to `YES` for Debug and `NO` for Release.

This has one MAJOR drawback however.  Code such as...

```
NSUInteger bob = 12234;
NSLog(@"bob %lu", bob);
```

Should produce the following type of warning (and therefore error in our case):

> Values of type 'NSUInteger' should not be used as format arguments;
>   add an explicit cast to 'unsigned long' instead

HOWEVER when developers are building and testing locally they DO NOT ENCOUNTER this warning/error but when they commit to our repository and our continous integration runs `xcodebuild` from the command line the warning is encountered and their build fails.  This is obviously rather frustrating.

I assume this has something to do with the difference between what architecture's are being build when using Xcode and when using `xcodebuild` from the command line.

I have uploaded a sample project here...

https://github.com/OliverPearmain/ArchitectureDependantCompileWarning

I've included 2 schemes.  If you compile for an iPhone 6S simulator using the "ArchitectureDependantCompileWarning" (which uses the Debug build configuration and thus `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH==YES`) you get no warning and things compile fine.  If you use the "ArchitectureDependantCompileWarning-FAILS" scheme (which uses the Release build configuration and thus `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH==NO`) then the warning is encountered and compilation fails.

I would like somehow to ensure that this warning is ALWAYS encountered when building for the simulator with `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH==NO`.  Is this possible?

Comment: I would assume that this is not possible, but I may be wrong. The warning occurs, because an `unsigned int` is passed when an `unsigned long` is expected. So when `NSUInteger` is `unsigned long` it all looks good. I could imagine, that one can adjust the build process to create some kind of tag file for each required architecture at the end of a successful build and version control rejects the commit, if the tag files are not valid (whatever this may mean in detail - maybe tag file is valid if it is newer than all source files?).

Comment: The only way I've been able to catch these is to always build for "Generic iOS Device" even in Debug mode, which has the same practical effect (as I understand it) as ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO. But if you're going to do that, might as well just build it for all archs even in Debug mode, which is inconvenient, obviously. Perhaps adjust your local unit test target (which I assume devs run locally prior to commit) to build for all archs?

Comment: As some practical advice, %zd will print NSInteger correctly and without warning on any architecture, so using %zd would be a good habit.

Comment: @gnasher729 the OP is using unsigned types so I think they should be using `%tu` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is the change in word length when the 5s came out.  In other words, the 5s and greater iPhones have a 64-bit processor, while all previous iPhones had a 32-bit processor.

Here's the actually typedefs for `NSUInteger`

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

You can see that for a 32-bit processor, `NSUInteger` is explicitly defined as a `unsigned int` whereas for a 64-bit processor, `NSUInteger` is explicitly defends as a `unsigned long`.

So, looking at this code...

```
NSUInteger bob = 12234;
NSLog(@"bob %lu", bob);
```

For a 4s, this `NSLog` has a mismatch since `NSUInteger` is explicitly defined as a `unsigned int` and the format specifier `%lu` is a `unsigned long`.  This very explicit mismatch is the reason that the warning exists for 32-bit processors.  For a 64-bit processor there is no mismatch and thus no warning.

The suggested fix in the warning assumes that you intended to use the `unsigned long`.  However, here is an alternative solution.

```
NSUInteger bob = 12234;
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
NSLog(@"bob %lu", bob);
#else
NSLog(@"bob %u", bob);
#endif
```

The bottom line is that what you are trying to do is to produce a mismatch warning when there is no mismatch, which is neither appropriate nor possible.

EDIT:

This isn't a case of a mismatch error failing to manifest as a warning/error. There literally is not a mismatch. The only way for this error to show up is for there to actually be a mismatch. There will only be a mismatch if you are building against architectures for which the definition of `NSUInteger` would create a mismatch in the specific code that you mentioned. There is already a standard way to make this happen: **set "Build Active Architecture Only" to NO for all of your schemes**.

Comment: Right, but this does not answer the question of how to turn these word length warnings on always for all platforms.

Comment: My keyboard battery died and my answer got submitted before I was done.  I changed the battery and finished my answer.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to right up this answer for the benefit of others.  However I am perfectly aware of the reasons and history behind the behaviour I've described.  What I am specifical asking in my OP is for a way to ensure this error manifests for those less ignorant than I even when they build to certain simulators.

Comment: This isn't a case of a mismatch error failing to manifest as a warning/error. There literally is not a mismatch. The only way for this error to show up is for there to actually be an error. There is a way to make this happen: set "Build Active Architecture Only" to NO for all of your schemes. I hope this helps.  Cheers!